# Bright artefacts in Beast lightmapping of a Unity3D scene

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I don't understand, how the following can be possible (look at the screenshot).

[image]

One of the edges of the "C" sign has a light. But there isn't any light. I has something to do with the Beast lightmapper. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

My lightmapping settings are:

- mode: Directional Lighting
- Quality: Hight
- Bounces: 4
- Sky Light Intensity: 0
- Bounce Bootst: 0.25
- Bounce Intensity: 0.25
- Final Gather Rays: 500
- Contrast Threshold: 0.022
- Interpolation: 0.262
- Interpolation Points: 16
- Ambient Occlusion: 0
- LOD Surface Distance: 1
- Lightmap Resolution: 50
- Lightmap Padding: 1

Lightmap UVs were generated by Unity3d

Comment: Drag the interpolation all the way down and see if the problem remains.

Comment: didnt help... the same screenshot...(

Answer (score 0):

Choose the C model from Unity's assets at `Normals & Tangents ->  Normals Options` Change it to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but if anyone stumbles on this thread while lookig for something else, it's most likely due to a low padding in the lightmap atlasing. I think the default is set to no padding ( 0 texels. Up that a little bit to 2, 4, 8?), currently it seems that some light bake from another object is bleeding on that C.